# If a principal bundle has a global section, then it is the trivial bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let be $(P, M, \pi, G)$ a principal G-bundle. Suppose that there is a section $\sigma: M \to P$. I want to prove that $P \cong M \times G$. I built $f: M\times G \to P$ such that $f(p, g) = \sigma(p) \cdot g$ where $\cdot$ is the right action on the bundle. I can prove that this is smooth and bijective, but I cannot prove that this is a diffeomorphism. My idea is to use the global rank theorem, but I can prove only that the map has constant rank o*n each fiber*, where the action is transitive. How can I prove that the rank is the same everywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the fact that $P$ is locally trivial.  To check that $f$ is a diffeomorphism, we can work locally over $M$, and thus assume that $P$ is actually the trivial bundle $M\times G$.  Our smooth section $\sigma$ then has the form $\sigma(p)=(p,\tau(p))$ for some smooth function $\tau:M\to G$, so then our putative diffeomorphism is the function $f:M\times G\to M\times G$ given by $f(p,g)=(p,\tau(p)\cdot g)$.  You can then think about the rank of this map as you suggest, but the easiest way to see it is a diffeomorphism is to just write down its inverse: $f^{-1}(p,g)=(p,\tau(p)^{-1}\cdot g)$.  This inverse function is smooth since $\tau$ and the inverse map on $G$ are both smooth.